# Is this a good blog structure?

Tags: php, mysql

Im programming my own simple blog with comments in php and mysql. I have one database, and I have one table for posts, (called posts) and for each post I make I manually create a new table called comments1,comments2,comments3, etc. Each blog post has an id and when I retrieve the comments for a post I use a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments".$id."`"
```

When I add user text to a comment I use:

```
htmlspecialchars(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']));
```

Is this structure ok or is there a better way I'm missing?

Also, would creating a different database for comments be a better practice than grouping it with the posts database? Does having 2 dbconnect functions in one file slow down performance by a lot? And one last worry: how do i make absolutely sure that my php files aren't served to the user as plaintext, because then they could see db login info and such.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should ask one question per question.

Comment: I'm glad to see the use of mysql_real_escape_string; However, if not applied on $id, one might be able to inject through that as well. Just a little note.

Comment: PHP files are compiled before anything is ever rendered by Apache.

Answer (score 13):

No, this is **TERRIBLE** structure.

Make one `comments` table and store all comments in there, along with corresponding `post_id`.

Add an index on `post_id` and you'll be able to quickly get all comments for a given post.